# Gantt diagram and pdflscape

Tags: fancyhdr, pgfgantt, pdflscape

I'm trying to put a gantt diagram (using `pgfgantt` package) into landscape mode (using `pdflscape` package), but I have encountered a problem:

It seems that, either because of `pgfgantt`, `pdflscape` or `fancyhdr`, my Gantt diagram goes over the margins ---i.e., goes over the right margin of of the page (on lanscape layout, as shown in the picture below).
[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
            y unit title=0.4cm,
            y unit chart=0.5cm,
            canvas/.style={fill=none, draw=black!7, line width=.75pt},
            vgrid,
            title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
            title left shift=.05,
            title right shift=-.05,
            title height=1,
            title/.style={fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
            bar/.style={fill=barblue},
            incomplete/.style={fill=white},
            progress label text={},
            bar height=0.7,
            group right shift=0,
            group top shift=.6,
            group height=.3,
            group peaks={}{}{.2}]{36}

            %labels
            \gantttitle[title/.style={draw=none}]{2013}{18}
            \gantttitle[title/.style={draw=none}]{2014}{18} \\
            \gantttitle{Jul}{3}
            \gantttitle{Aug}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Set}{3}
            \gantttitle{Oct}{3}
            \gantttitle{Nov}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Dec}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Jan}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Feb}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Mar}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Apr}{3} 
            \gantttitle{May}{3} 
            \gantttitle{Jun}{3}\\

            % Parameter Selection
            \ganttgroup{1. Parameter Selection}{1}{9}\\ %elem0
            \ganttbar[progress=10]{Tests}{1}{4}\\
            \ganttmilestone{Final parameters}{9} \\

            % Algorithm Development
            \ganttgroup{2. Algorithm Development and testing}{10}{33} \\ 
            \ganttbar[progress=2]{2.1 Optimization}{10}{19} \\
            \ganttmilestone{Target function}{13} \\
            \ganttbar[progress=1]{2.2 Neural Network}{20}{33} \\
            \ganttmilestone{M 2.2}{33} \\       

            % Algorithm Testing
            \ganttgroup{3. Algorithm testing}{25}{30} \\ 


        \end{ganttchart}
    \caption{Gantt diagram for 2013--2014 Academic year}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Your chart is 715pt wide (about 10in or 25cm), while the text area available (with the normal setup of `article`) is 550pt (about 7.5in or 19cm). It's obvious it doesn't fit, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg, yeap, I want to know how to make it fit.  I tried with both `\textwidth` and `\textheight`... I want to set it automatically so my chart never exceeds the maximum space

Comment: Realistically, you'll have to scale the plot using an appropriate box. Would that be an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE no longer works since the `pgfgantt` package has been updated since you asked, but I don't think the solution depends on the change. One option is to scale the chart in a resize box.

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{\textheight}{\begin{ganttchart} ... }
```

I use `\linewidth` since the `landscape` environment does not set the `textwidth` as I would expect. It is not clear if you always want the chart to fill a page or not. You can save the chart in a box

```
\sbox0{\begin{ganttchart} ... }
```

and then do

```
\ifdim\wd0>\linewidth\relax%
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox{0}}%
\else%
  \usebox{0}%
\fi%
```

to conditionally scale the chart.

A drawback of this type of scaling is the text gets scaled, which may not be what you want. An alternative approach is to use the `x unit` key value. The `x unit` influences the width of the chart, but it is not the only thing (there are also the labels and the number of units). A not fully automated solution is

```
\sbox0{2. Algorithm Development and testing}
\newlength{\chartlongestlabel}
\setlength{\chartlongestlabel}{\wd0}
\newlength{\chartwidth}
\setlength{\chartwidth}{\textheight}
\addtolength{\chartwidth}{-\chartlongestlabel}

\begin{ganttchart}[x unit=0.027\chartwidth, ... ]{1}{36}
```

where `0.027` is about `1/36` and the longest may not have the exact size depending on how you set the formatting keys.